# Nexus 5 and 7 returns different screen size dependning on orientation

Tags: android, titanium

I use these  to get the screen width and height (Titanium)

```
Ti.Platform.displayCaps.platformWidth,
Ti.Platform.displayCaps.platformHeight,
```

As for  nexus7.

it returns these values when orientation is landscape.

```
[INFO]  Width:1920
[INFO]  Height:1104
ratio:0.575 ( Height / Width)
```

When orientation is portrait

```
[INFO]  Width:1200
[INFO]  Height:1824
ratio:0.657
```

At first I think it is because of navigation bar,

but even regarding navigation bar, it differs too much.

When in Landscape, it is similar to 8:5

However in portrait it is similar to 16:9

Real device is smilar to 8:5.

Why this difference happens??

I am using titanium though, this occurs when use native android code??